# Exclude user from OOM killer in unix

Tags: out-of-memory

Is there anyway to exclude some users from the out-of- memory killer in Unix? On the other way, can I set priority for user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to instruct OOM to ignore specific user processes. Though you can instruct it to ignore a specific process and based on that you can construct a loop which will check all processes for specific user and update it via cron or whatever way you like. Cycle itself will look something like that:

```
while read r_pid ; do 
    echo -16 | sudo tee /proc/$r_pid/oom_adj ; 
done < <(pgrep -U Yoki)
```

you can wrap it in script and schedule to be run once per minute or any interval you like.

or you can completely disable OOM with

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
echo "vm.overcommit_memory=2" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

though it is not recommended way at all, as it might lead to unexpected behaviour such as kernel panics or system hang.

Comment: Change -17 to something like -16 and the user's processes will be picked before other "critical" system processes.

Comment: Good point. Updated. Thx.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting `overcommit_memory=2`, it's just that certain applications (java, browsers) try to gobble up more virtual memory than is available, so they fail.  You might actually run out of memory, so monitor swap with a monitoring program, and if swap usage begins to climb, it might be a problem.